# How would I extract a .img file

Tags: disk-image, extract

I am trying to extract a .img file (hard disk image with with Chromium OS on it). I have not been able to find any way to do this other than mounting it but that is not usable because it shows up as multiple drives so I cannot repack it.

Answer (score 14):

You do not extract an `.img`; you mount it. Example:

```
mkdir /mnt/ChromeOS
mount -o loop image.img /mnt/ChromeOS/
```

and this will list the contents:

```
cd /mnt/ChromeOS/
ls -l
```

Mind that `.img` can also be zipped. If that is the case (unlikely though) you also need to `gunzip` it.

Comment: You can extract an img... Its just a container....... Common process when it comes to SBC's.

Comment: This does not work if the img contains multiple partitions, at least it fails for me. Using kpartx works instead.

Answer (score 7):

### You can use **`kpartx`** - create device maps from partition tables

Install the package `kpartx` and run

```
sudo kpartx ...
```

From `man kpartx`:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> kpartx [-a | -d | -l] [-v] wholedisk
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> This  tool, derived from util-linux' partx, reads partition tables on specified device and creates device maps over partitions
>   segments detected. It is called from hotplug upon device  maps
>   creation and deletion.
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> To mount all the partitions in a raw disk image:
>
> ```
> kpartx -av disk.img
> ```

### You can clone from the image file to a drive

You can clone from the `.img` [image] file to a drive, for example a USB pendrive, that is big enough. This is the basic intention of the file.

You can use [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) for that purpose. It works with compressed image files too (when compressed with `gzip` and `xz`), `.img.gz` and `.img.xz` files.

After the cloning you will see the partitions for example with

```
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
sudo parted -ls
```

After cloning you can mount and unmount the partition(s) on the drive 'as usual'.

Comment: kpartx works, thank you! But to mount the desired partition you also have to `sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop?p? mountpoint` where the two `?` should be replaced with those output by kpartx.

Comment: That's right, @MauroMolinari. Thanks for this comment, it is helpful for new users, who want to mount the the partition; they should notice `mapper` in the path for the block device.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found to extract .img files on Ubuntu is using [PEAZIP FREE ARCHIVER](http://www.peazip.org/index.html), through its windows(ish) GUI.

First you have to install a bunch of i386 dependencies and so you'll have to enable i386 packages too:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libxft2:i386
```

Then [download](http://www.peazip.org/peazip-linux.html) PeaZip Package and install it or simply run:

```
wget https://osdn.net/dl/peazip/peazip_6.5.1.LINUX.GTK2-2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i peazip_6.5.1.LINUX.GTK2-2_all.deb
```

Finally launch `peazip` and go through the GUI to extract .img files. (I can confirm it works on chromium os .img files for me.)

Note: You can always rely on [gdebi](https://launchpad.net/gdebi) for handling dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I use the MATE desktop, so I mount ISO or IMG disk images using the MATE Disk Image Mounter. MATE Disk Image Mounter is a file tree dialog that you run to select an image file to mount.

[image: MATE Disk Image Mounter]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Etcher.io to write the image on a USB drive or SD card and work with the files and finally repack using disk-utility.